# How to read data from Firebase realtime database using loop

Tags: ios, swift, database, firebase, indexing

How to read data from firebase realtime database by indexPath or something like that?

that is my base:
[image]

JSON:

```
    {
  "2020" : {
"May" : {
      "01" : {
        "Room:2" : {
          "Shift2" : {
            "3" : {
              "breaks" : {
                "break d2M" : {
                  "endTime" : "00:39:22",
                  "startTime" : "00:24:17",
                  "totalTime" : "0 h 15 min 5 sec",
                  "totalTime70" : "905"
                }
              },
              "endNotes" : {
                "Notes" : "15 boxes worth also filled and sealed and labelled as cutter broke.",
                "Pod" : "A-35",
                "customer" : "Mc",
                "numberOfPeople" : "4",
                "quantity" : "18432",
                "reasonOfRejects" : "Seal",
                "rejects" : "5",
                "teamLeader" : "Lydia "
              },
              "times" : {
                "endCleaning" : "01:32:14",
                "endTime" : "01:32:12",
                "endTime70" : "15927",
                "setUpToEndCleaning" : "4 h 25 min 30 sec",
                "startCleaning" : "01:32:13",
                "startRunToEndEun" : "4 h 25 min 27 sec",
                "timeOfCleaning" : "0 h 0 min 1 sec",
                "timeOfCleaning70" : "1",
                "timeOfWork" : "4 h 25 min 27 sec",
                "timeOfWork70" : "15930"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      },
      "22" : {
        "Shift1" : [ null, {
          "breaks" : {
            "break 50B" : {
              "endTime" : "8:28:56 AM",
              "startTime" : "8:28:55 AM",
              "totalTime" : "0 hours  0 minutes  1 seconds",
              "totalTime70" : "1"
            },
            "break NLr" : {
              "endTime" : "8:28:12 AM",
              "startTime" : "8:28:11 AM",
              "totalTime" : "0 hours  0 minutes  1 seconds",
              "totalTime70" : "1"
            }
          },
          "endNotes" : {
            "Notes" : "Test note",
            "Pod" : "B-22",
            "customer" : "Germany",
            "numberOfPeople" : "9",
            "quantity" : "4200",
            "reasonOfRejects" : "Test",
            "rejects" : "30",
            "teamLeader" : "Borys"
          },
          "issues" : {
            "Issue d0c" : {
              "Note" : "fight",
              "Type" : "Multivac - not sealing",
              "issueStartTime" : "8:28:09 AM",
              "solvedTime" : "8:28:10 AM",
              "timeOfIssue" : "0 hours  0 minutes  1 seconds",
              "timeOfIssue70" : "1"
            },
            "Issue nCP" : {
              "Note" : "sdf sdfgsdfg ",
              "Type" : "Eric - not dosing correctly",
              "issueStartTime" : "8:28:17 AM",
              "solvedTime" : "8:28:19 AM",
              "timeOfIssue" : "0 hours  0 minutes  2 seconds",
              "timeOfIssue70" : "2"
            }
          },
          "main" : {
            "didSend" : "NO",
            "id" : "ROOM2POD3",
            "numberOfTargets" : "3999",
            "product" : "PRODUCT: HFN-0007 Cajun Spice Mix / Cajun Kryddmix / Cajun Spice Mix 4g"
          },
          "times" : {
            "endCleaning" : "8:28:59 AM",
            "endTime" : "8:28:45 AM",
            "endTime70" : "48",
            "setUpTime" : "0 hours  0 minutes  30 seconds",
            "setUpTime70" : "30",
            "startCleaning" : "8:28:48 AM",
            "startSetUpTime" : "8:27:27 AM",
            "startTime" : "8:27:57 AM",
            "timeOfCleaning" : "0 hours  0 minutes  11 seconds",
            "timeOfCleaning70" : "11",
            "timeOfWork" : "0 hours  1 minutes  2 seconds",
            "timeOfWork70" : "62"
          }
        }, {
          "breaks" : {
            "break tmQ" : {
              "endTime" : "8:34:37 AM",
              "startTime" : "8:34:35 AM",
              "totalTime" : "0 h 0 min 2 sec",
              "totalTime70" : "2"
            }
          },
          "endNotes" : {
            "Notes" : "I have no idea",
            "Pod" : "C-35",
            "customer" : "HeliHansen",
            "numberOfPeople" : "8",
            "quantity" : "900",
            "reasonOfRejects" : "Something",
            "rejects" : "20",
            "teamLeader" : "Mark"
          },
          "issues" : {
            "Issue Epe" : {
              "Note" : "dsfgsdfg",
              "Type" : "Hot Water Tank - hot water has ran cold",
              "issueStartTime" : "8:34:24 AM",
              "solvedTime" : "8:34:25 AM",
              "timeOfIssue" : "0 h 0 min 1 sec",
              "timeOfIssue70" : "1"
            },
            "Issue fEq" : {
              "Note" : "sdfgsdfg",
              "Type" : "Hot Water Tank - hot water has ran cold",
              "issueStartTime" : "8:34:28 AM",
              "solvedTime" : "8:34:33 AM",
              "timeOfIssue" : "0 h 0 min 5 sec",
              "timeOfIssue70" : "5"
            }
          },
          "main" : {
            "didSend" : "NO",
            "id" : "UFNGU877",
            "numberOfTargets" : "800",
            "product" : "PRODUCT: HFN-0006 Cajun Spice Mix / Cajun Kryddmix / Cajun Spice Mix 2g"
          },
          "times" : {
            "endCleaning" : "8:35:15 AM",
            "endTime" : "8:35:09 AM",
            "endTime70" : "53",
            "setUpTime" : "0 h 0 min 15 sec",
            "setUpTime70" : "15",
            "startCleaning" : "8:35:10 AM",
            "startSetUpTime" : "8:34:01 AM",
            "startTime" : "8:34:16 AM",
            "timeOfCleaning" : "0 h 0 min 5 sec",
            "timeOfCleaning70" : "5",
            "timeOfWork" : "0 h 0 min 59 sec",
            "timeOfWork70" : "59"
          }
        }, {
          "breaks" : {
            "break DKf" : {
              "endTime" : "10:20:05",
              "startTime" : "10:20:04",
              "totalTime" : "0 h 0 min 1 sec",
              "totalTime70" : "1"
            },
            "break s8y" : {
              "endTime" : "10:20:22",
              "startTime" : "10:20:20",
              "totalTime" : "0 h 0 min 2 sec",
              "totalTime70" : "2"
            }
          },
          "endNotes" : {
            "Notes" : "Test test",
            "Pod" : "C-35",
            "customer" : "Algeier",
            "numberOfPeople" : "9",
            "quantity" : "11000",
            "reasonOfRejects" : "Test",
            "rejects" : "500",
            "teamLeader" : "Natan"
          },
          "issues" : {
            "Issue Xjh" : {
              "Note" : "buvbtg",
              "Type" : "Hot Water Tank - hot water has ran cold",
              "issueStartTime" : "10:20:14",
              "solvedTime" : "10:20:18",
              "timeOfIssue" : "0 h 0 min 4 sec",
              "timeOfIssue70" : "4"
            }
          },
          "main" : {
            "didSend" : "NO",
            "id" : "NATAN",
            "numberOfTargets" : "10000",
            "product" : "PRODUCT: HFN-0008 Cashews 20g"
          },
          "times" : {
            "endCleaning" : "10:21:04",
            "endTime" : "10:20:47",
            "endTime70" : "40",
            "setUpTime" : "0 h 0 min 23 sec",
            "setUpTime70" : "23",
            "setUpToEndCleaning" : "0 h 1 min 20 sec",
            "startCleaning" : "10:20:48",
            "startSetUpTime" : "10:19:44",
            "startTime" : "10:20:07",
            "timeOfCleaning" : "0 h 0 min 16 sec",
            "timeOfCleaning70" : "16",
            "timeOfWork" : "0 h 0 min 57 sec",
            "timeOfWork70" : "57"
          }
        } ]
      }
```

I want to read all "numberOfTargets" and print the values. How can I make path like this:
"2020 -> May -> 11 -> (first index) -> main -> numberOfTargets" ?
It is not constant, so I don't know name of it. Is it possible to do that by index number?
I've tried to do that for different ways, and I didn't find solution.

I also tried something like this, but I thins it's wrong, and I don't know how can I do that :)

```
    func allTargets() {
    let ref1 = ref.child("\(av.currentYear())/\(av.currentMonth())/\(av.currentDay())")
    ref1.observeSingleEvent(of: .value) { (snapshot) in
        let value = snapshot.value as? NSDictionary
        let numberOfTargets = value?.allKeys
        print(numberOfTargets)
    }
}
```

Comment: It’s a good idea to include code and structures as *text*, not images. That way, if they are needed in an answer, they can be copied and pasted. To get your Firebase structure, use the Firebase console->Export JSON and copy and paste a snippet of your structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a bunch of ways to get to that data; I'll show two, a coding solution and then an alternative structure solution

**Coding solution:**

The ID's are unknown but the path to the parent node of those ID's is. So create a reference to the most-known key (the parent, 11) and then read the child nodes underneath.

Assemble them into an array of DataSnapshots (to keep the order) and then iterate over that array, getting the child data at numberOfTargets.

```
func readNumberOfTargets() {
    let mayRef = self.ref.child("2020").child("May") //self.ref points to my firebase
    let dayRef = mayRef.child("11")
    dayRef.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { snapshot in
        let childSnaps = snapshot.children.allObjects as! [DataSnapshot]
        for child in childSnaps {
            let mainSnap = child.childSnapshot(forPath: "main")
            let numTargets = mainSnap.childSnapshot(forPath: "numberOfTargets")
            print(child.key, numTargets)
        }
    })
}
```

and the output

```
Jan Snap (numberOfTargets) 80
borys Snap (numberOfTargets) 77
ftfvdf Snap (numberOfTargets) 99
```

Note that it looks like the numberOfTargets is being stored as a string so use this if that's the case

```
let numTargets = mainSnap.childSnapshot(forPath: "numberOfTargets").value as? String ?? "No Targets"
```

if it's being stored as an Int, use this

```
let numTargets = mainSnap.childSnapshot(forPath: "numberOfTargets").value as? Int ?? 0
```

**Alternative Structure Solution:**

It's common practice to denormalize your data in NoSQL databases and also using compound keys to get to it. In this case, we'll do both and create a seperate node that contains a highly flattened structure that's super easy to get to

```
TargetCount
   2020_May_11_Jan: 80
   2020_May_11_borys: 77
   2020_May_11_ftfvdf: 99
```

So when you want the target count for each node, it can just be read based on the path. In other words, when this node is created

```
2020
   May
      11
         Jan
```

they key 'Jan' (the unknown key per your question) is returned when that node is created. So at the same time write that path to the TargetCount node

```
TargetCount
   2020_May_11_Jan: 80
```

As you iterate over the child nodes, you'll know the unknown by descontstucting the key string

```
2020_May_11 and then the Jan value is 80
```

You could also do this if you want to isolate the specific dates

```
TargetCount
   2020_May_11
      Jan:80
      borys: 77
      ftfvdf: 99
```

Comment: Thank you so much! You helped me a lot :)